# Нужно вывести определенную часть URL адреса

Tags: python, строки, url

Формат ссылки:

```
https://site.com/x/xxx-xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxx/Xz3M_7YhbfDv6YqkZYn7JH61ZNm4Px57
```

Нужно получить последнюю часть `Xz3M_7YhbfDv6YqkZYn7JH61ZNm4Px57` в качестве строки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
url = 'https://site.com/x/xxx-xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxx/Xz3M_7YhbfDv6YqkZYn7JH61ZNm4Px57'

print(url.split('/')[-1])
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!